# Using my own String class with the << operator

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, ostream

I am looking for a way to use an ostream with my custom string class and overload the operator << to stream to the buffer which i can then flush to anywhere i want (in my case its just gonna be printed in a window)

I'm reasonably new to the inner workings of iostream's but from my understanding the method i've seen of making std::stringbuf a base of my custom stringstream would not work because the stringbuf deals with the std::string.

in essence i want to able to do this (or similar):

```
MyStringClass string
MyOutput << "hello" << string << "World" << std::endl;
```

Where MyOutput can be changed to print to anywhere i want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem. Define your class, and within it's definition add an `ostream& operator<<(const String&);`.

Inside that operator, you can code whatever handling you want (look at std::string for inspiration)

Comment: is it that simple? but the ostream that my string is outputting to, doesnt that deal with std::strings? or am i simply ignoring that, and doing the 'printing' inside the operator definition? thanks

Comment: `ostream` is the type of `cout`; it has no relation to std::string. My declaration would allow you to use `cout << yourstring` but you are not bound to use cout; use whatever destination you want.

Comment: @LukeBourne Inside your `<<` function, you have to output some other type, such as `std::string`, that already has an output method defined.